# "Change of variable" in Limit

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$. Let $(p,q), (v_1,v_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

Are the following limits the same?

1) $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(p+hv_1,q+hv_2)-f(p,q+hv_2)}{h}$$

2) $$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(p+hv_1,q+\epsilon v_2)-f(p,q+\epsilon v_2)}{h}$$

The idea is I wish to simplify expression 1 to expression 2 (if possible).

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they are not always the same. Here is a simple counterexample: Let $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2}{y}$. Set $q,p=0$ and $v_1,v_2=1$. Then you first expression always equals $1$ for any $h>0$ and so has limit $1$. However, your second expression always equals $\frac{h}{\epsilon}$ so the inner limit is $0$ for any $\epsilon$ and so the outer limit is also zero.

Answer (score 1):

No, the first limit is a "rate of change" in the direction of $(v_1,v_2).$ The second limit is a "rate of change" in the $x$ direction.

More precisely, the first limit is the directional derivative $D_{(v_1,v_2)}f(p,q).$ The second limit is, assuming $v_1\ne 0,$ $v_1\partial f/\partial x\,(p,q).$ (I'm assuming $f$ has continuous partial derivatives here.)

The two agree if $v_2 = 0.$